# Unicode error in python when printing a list

Tags: python, unicode

Edit: http://pastebin.com/W4iG3tjS - the file

I have a text file encoded in utf8 with some Cyrillic text it. To load it, I use the following code:

```
import codecs
fopen = codecs.open('thefile', 'r', encoding='utf8')
fread = fopen.read()
```

`fread` dumps the file on the screen all unicodish (escape sequences). `print fread` displays it in readable form (ASCII I guess).

I then try to split it and write it to an empty file with no encoding:

```
a = fread.split()
for l in a: 
    print>>dasFile, l
```

But I get the following error message: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-13: ordinal not in range(128)`

Is there a way to dump `fread.split()` into a file? How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've opened and read the file via `codecs.open()`, it's been decoded to Unicode. So to output it you need to encode it again, presumably back to UTF-8.

```
for l in a:
    dasFile.write(l.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: @abruski: make sure you `.close()` the file to ensure any changes are flushed from the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

print is going to use the default encoding, which is normally "ascii". So you see that error with print. But you can open a file and write directly to it.

```
a = fopen.readlines() # returns a list of lines already, with line endings intact
# do something with a
dasFile.writelines(a) # doesn't add line endings, expects them to be present already.
```

assuming the lines in a are encoded already.

PS. You should also investigate the `io` module.

Comment: @abruski oh, yes, you split it. I forgot about that. I'll edit the answer.